# click multiple href download links

Tags: javascript, click, href

```
function clickLink(link) {     
var cancelled = false;
if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null);
        cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
        cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
    if (!cancelled) {
        window.location = link.href;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    var x=links[i];
    if(x.href.indexOf('download.mp4') > -1) { 
        console.log(x.href); x.click(); 
        }
    } 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    var x=links[i];
    if(x.href.indexOf('download.mp4') > -1) {
        console.log(x.href); clickLink(x); 
    }
}
```

With above code the purpose was to download all video links on one page. Although console log contains all the links I want only one link really gets downloaded. 
There are no errors or warnings, how can I achieve this ?
Also tried without window.location line, no luck...

following worked out now:

```
function JustclickLink(link) {     
       var cancelled = false;
if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null);
        cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
        cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }

    if (!cancelled) {
    window.open(link.href,'_blank');         
    }
}
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){ 
    var x=links[i];
    if(x.href.indexOf('download.mp4') > -1){
        console.log(x.href); JustclickLink(x); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jquery alternative to what you seek.
Window.open should be used for multiple downloads, as window.location will trigger only once in the code run.

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
window.open($(this).attr("href"),'_blank');
});
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```